# How to use local development server with October CMS

Tags: octobercms

I'd like to use a local dev server with October CMS (e.g. `php artisan serve`). I created a `.env` file with `APP_ENV=dev`, otherwise it is a default installation from following the instructions on October's website. The site works when accessed via Apache. I didn't find any information on using a dev server on the Forums or SO.

This is the error I get after starting the dev server, and when I first try to access the page in a browser:

```
PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/october-cms/server.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/october-cms/server.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

I just started working with the product, and haven't fully worked through the documentation. I'm not sure what the `server.php` file is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked [this question](https://octobercms.com/forum/post/using-a-local-development-server-with-october-cms) on the October CMS forum after it went unanswered here for a few days. The problem was that I installed October via the GUI installer, instead of the command line. The missing file (`server.php`) is [here](https://github.com/octobercms/october/blob/master/server.php).